# How to write a large set of equations in the most appropriate way?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, article

I have a set of over two dozen equations that takes almost two pages. I want to write them neatly so that they look clean and readable. What I currently have looks horrible. I am at my wit's end and cannot figure out in what way I can align/write them so that they look the best they can. This is what I have now (it's only one page, there's another page that I am not including here)
[image]
I guess there is certainly a better way to typeset all these equations. What I truly want to understand is what the best practices are in this case when one has dozens of equations -- some long, some short; some just one-liner, while others seem to be running into multiple lines. How to align/write them so that they look less cruel to eyes? Here's the file I have for the list of equations (kindly forgive me for posting the entire code, I am conscioulsly avoiding using the term MWE because it certainly does not look like that to me but I include it all here because I reckon it might be what's needed to think about a solution to this issue):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb,epsfig}
\begin{document}
\section{System of Loglinear Equations}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \beta^{P}\gamma^{P}\mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{C}_{t+1}^{P}              - \left(1 + \left(\gamma^{P}\right)^{2}\beta^{P}\right)     \widehat{C}_{t}^{P} + \gamma^{P}\widehat{C}_{t-1}^{P} = \left(1     - \beta^{P}\gamma^{P}\right)\left(1 - \gamma^{P}\right)    \widehat{\lambda}^{P} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{\lambda}_{t+1}^{P} & = \widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{P} - \hat{R}_{t}^{D}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \left(1 - \beta^{P}\right)\left(\widehat{\varsigma}_{t} - \widehat{H}_{t}^{P}\right) + \beta^{P}\mathbb{E}_{t}\left[\widehat{\lambda}_{t+1}^{P} + \widehat{Q}_{t+1}^{H}\right] = \widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{P} + \widehat{Q}_{t}^{H}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \widehat{\iota}_{t} = \widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{P} +    \widehat{W}_{t}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \beta^{E}\gamma^{E}\mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{C}_{t+1}^{E} - \left(1 + \left(\gamma^{E}\right)^{2}\beta^{E}\right)\widehat{C}_{t}^{E} + \gamma^{E}\widehat{C}_{t-1}^{E} = \left(1 - \beta^{E}\gamma^{E}\right)\left(1 - \gamma^{E}\right)\widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{E}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \widehat{R}_{t}^{L} + \beta^{E}R^{L}\mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{\lambda}_{t+1}^{E} + \left(1 - \beta^{E}R^{L}\right)\widehat{\mu}_{t}^{E} = \widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{E}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \widehat{W}_{t} = \widehat{Y}_{t} - \widehat{N}_{t}  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\left(\widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{E} + \widehat{Q}_{t}^{H}\right) = \beta^{E}\mathbb{E}_{t}\big(\widehat{\lambda}_{t+1}^{E} & + \widehat{Q}_{t+1}^{H}\big) + \bigg(\frac{1}{R^{L}} - \beta^{E}\bigg)\theta\mathbb{E}_{t}\big(\widehat{\mu}_{t}^{E} + \widehat{\theta}_{t} + \widehat{W}_{t+1}^{H}\big) + \ldots \\
& \mathrel{\phantom{=}} \ldots + \bigg[\big(1 - \beta^{E}\big) - \theta\bigg(\frac{1}{R^{L}} - \beta^{E}\bigg)\bigg]\mathbb{E}_{t}\big[\widehat{\lambda}_{t+1}^{E} + \widehat{Y}_{t+1} - \widehat{H}_{t}^{E}\big]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \widehat{Q}_{t}^{K} = \big[1 & - \beta^{E}\big(1 - \delta\big) - \theta\big(\frac{1}{R^{L}} - \beta^{E}\big)\big]\mathbb{E}_{t}\big[\widehat{\lambda}_{t+1}^{E} - \lambda_{t}^{E} + \widehat{Y}_{t+1} - K_{t}\big] + \ldots \\
    & \ldots + \beta^{E}\big(1 - \delta\big)\mathbb{E}_{t}\big(\widehat{Q}_{t+1}^{K} + \widehat{\lambda}_{t+1}^{E} - \widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{E}\big) + \left(1 - \beta^{E}R^{L}\right)\frac{1}{R^{L}}\theta\mathbb{E}_{t}\left[\widehat{\mu}_{t}^{E} - \widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{E} + \widehat{\theta}_{t} + \widehat{Q}_{t+1}^{K}\right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \widehat{Q}_{t}^{K} = \left(1 + \beta^{E}\right)\Omega\widehat{I}_{t} - \beta^{E}\Omega\mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{I}_{t+1} - \Omega\widehat{I}_{t-1}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{\mu^{B}}{\beta^{P}}\widehat{\mu}_{t}^{B} & - \mu^{B}\gamma^{L}\big(1 - \rho_{s}\big)\mathbb{E}_{t}\mu_{t+1}^{B} = \big[p R^{L} - R^{D} + \big(1 - p\big)\tau R^{L} + \mu^{B}\gamma^{L}\big(1 - \rho_{s}\big)\big]\mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{q}_{t, t+1} + \ldots \\
    & \ldots + p R^{L}\left(\widehat{p}_{t} + \widehat{R}_{t}^{L}\right) - R^{D}\widehat{R}_{t}^{D} + \left(1 - p\right)\tau R^{L}\widehat{R}_{t}^{L} - p \tau R^{L}\widehat{p}_{t}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{\eta\xi\mu^{B}x}{\theta}\big(\widehat{\mu}_{t}^{B} & + \widehat{x}_{t} - \widehat{\theta}_{t}\big) = -\varpi\beta^{P}\big(R^{L}\big)^{2}L \theta\big(2\widehat{R}_{t}^{L} + \widehat{L}_{t} + \widehat{\theta}_{t} + \mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{q}_{t, t+1}\big) - \ldots \\
    & \ldots - \eta \varpi \beta^{P}R^{L}L\left(\widehat{R}_{t}^{L} + \widehat{L}_{L} + \mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{q}_{t, t+1}\right) + \varpi \tau \beta^{P}\alpha\theta^{2}R^{L}\left(\widehat{a}_{t} + 2\widehat{\theta}_{t} + \widehat{R}_{t}^{L} + \mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{q}_{t, t+1}\right) + \ldots \\
    & \ldots + \eta \varpi \tau \beta^{P} \theta a\left(\widehat{a}_{t} + \widehat{\theta}_{t} + \mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{q}_{t, t+1}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \xi\mu^{B}x\theta\left(\widehat{\mu}_{t}^{B} + \widehat{x}_{t} + \widehat{\theta}_{t}\right) = \theta\beta^{P}R^{L}pL\left(\widehat{\theta}_{t} + \widehat{R}_{t}^{L} + \widehat{p}_{t} + \widehat{L}_{t} + \mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{q}_{t, t+1}\right) + \eta \beta^{P}pL\left(\widehat{p}_{t} + \widehat{L}_{t} + \mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{q}_{t, t+1}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \widehat{s}_{t} = \rho_{s}\widehat{s}_{t, t-1} + \left(1 - \rho_{s}\right)\widehat{l}_{t}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \widehat{x}_{t} = \frac{\widehat{l}_{t}}{1 - \gamma^{L}} - \frac{\gamma^{L}\widehat{s}_{t-1}}{1 - \gamma^{L}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \widehat{L}_{t} = \widehat{l}_{t}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \widehat{Y}_{t} = \frac{C^{P}}{C}\widehat{C}_{t}^{P} + \frac{C^{E}}{Y}\widehat{C}_{t}^{E} + \frac{I}{Y}\widehat{I}_{t}  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}    
H^{P}\widehat{H}_{t}^{P} + H^{E}\widehat{H}_{t}^{E} = 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \widehat{L}_{t} = \widehat{D}_{t}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    C^{E}\widehat{C}_{t}^{E} & + R^{L}l\left(\widehat{R}_{t-1}^{L} + \widehat{l}_{t-1}\right) = Y\widehat{Y}_{t} - WN\left(\widehat{W}_{t} + \widehat{N}_{t}\right) - I\widehat{I}_{t} - Q^{H}H^{E}\left(\widehat{H}_{t}^{E} - \widehat{H}_{t-1}^{E}\right) + \ldots\\
    & \ldots + x\widehat{x}_{t} + \gamma^{L}s\widehat{s}_{t-1} + R^{L}L\left(\widehat{R}_{t-1}^{L} + \widehat{L}_{t-1}\right) -\tau a \widehat{a}_{t-1} - p R^{L}L\left(\widehat{p}_{t-1} + \widehat{R}_{t-1}^{L} + \widehat{L}_{t-1}\right) + \ldots \\
    & \ldots + \tau p a \left(\widehat{p}_{t-1} + \widehat{a}_{t-1}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \widehat{l}_{t} = \widehat{\theta}_{t} + \widehat{a}_{t} - \widehat{R}_{t}^{L}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \widehat{a}_{t} = \frac{Q^{H}H^{E}}{Q^{H}H^{E} + Q^{K}K}\mathbb{E}_{t}\left(\widehat{Q}_{t+1}^{H} + \widehat{H}_{t}^{E}\right) + \frac{Q^{K}K}{Q^{H}H^{E} + Q^{K}K}\mathbb{E}_{t}\left(\widehat{Q}_{t+1}^{K} + \widehat{K}_{t}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \widehat{Y}_{t} = \widehat{A}_{t} + \left(1 - \alpha\right)\widehat{N}_{t} + \alpha \phi \widehat{H}_{t-1}^{E} + \alpha \left(1 - \phi\right) \widehat{K}_{t-1} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \widehat{K}_{t} = \left(1 - \delta\right) \widehat{K}_{t-1} + \delta \widehat{I}_{t}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    p\widehat{p}_{t} = \varpi \theta \widehat{\theta}_{t}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \widehat{\kappa}_{t}^{E} = \widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{E} + \widehat{Q}_{t}^{K} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \widehat{q}_{t, t+1} = \widehat{\lambda}_{t+1}^{P} - \widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{P}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off topicish: `aligned` with no `&` nor `\\ ` doesn't make sense.  At that point, it's an expression, and you should drop the `aligned`.  And multiple `equation` in a row is a no-no.  Use `gather` if nothing else.  But I agree with Zarko's suggestion that you should have more explanatory text between the equations.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you'll like it:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, nccmath, mathtools}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}
\section{System of Loglinear Equations}
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{spreadlines}{2ex}
\begin{gather}
\beta^{P}\gamma^{P}\mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{C}_{t+1}^{P} - 
    \bigl(1 + (\gamma^{P}\bigr)^{2}\beta^{P}\bigr)     
    \widehat{C}_{t}^{P} + \gamma^{P}\widehat{C}_{t-1}^{P} 
     = \bigl(1 - \beta^{P}\gamma^{P}\bigr)\bigl(1 - \gamma^{P}\bigr) \widehat{\lambda}^{P} 
\mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{\lambda}_{t+1}^{P}  = \widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{P} - \hat{R}_{t}^{D}
\\
\left(1 - \beta^{P}\right)\left(\widehat{\varsigma}_{t} - \widehat{H}_{t}^{P}\right) + \beta^{P}\mathbb{E}_{t}\left[\widehat{\lambda}_{t+1}^{P} + \widehat{Q}_{t+1}^{H}\right] = \widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{P} + \widehat{Q}_{t}^{H}
\\
\widehat{\iota}_{t} = \widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{P} + \widehat{W}_{t}
\\
\beta^{E}\gamma^{E}\mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{C}_{t+1}^{E} - 
\left(1 + \left(\gamma^{E}\right)^{2}\beta^{E}\right)\widehat{C}_{t}^{E} + \gamma^{E}\widehat{C}_{t-1}^{E}
= \left(1 - \beta^{E}\gamma^{E}\right)\left(1 - \gamma^{E}\right)\widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{E}
\\
\widehat{R}_{t}^{L} + \beta^{E}R^{L}\mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{\lambda}_{t+1}^{E} + \left(1 - \beta^{E}R^{L}\right)\widehat{\mu}_{t}^{E} = \widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{E}
\\
\widehat{W}_{t} = \widehat{Y}_{t} - \widehat{N}_{t}
\\
\begin{multlined}
\left(\widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{E} + \widehat{Q}_{t}^{H}\right) = \beta^{E}\mathbb{E}_{t}\big(\widehat{\lambda}_{t+1}^{E} 
      + \widehat{Q}_{t+1}^{H}\big) + \bigg(\frac{1}{R^{L}} - \beta^{E}\bigg)\theta\mathbb{E}_{t}\big(\widehat{\mu}_{t}^{E} + \widehat{\theta}_{t} + \widehat{W}_{t+1}^{H}\big) + \ldots 
      \\
    \mathrel{\phantom{=}} \ldots + \bigg[\big(1 - \beta^{E}\big) - \theta\bigg(\frac{1}{R^{L}} - \beta^{E}\bigg)\bigg]\mathbb{E}_{t}\big[\widehat{\lambda}_{t+1}^{E} + \widehat{Y}_{t+1} - \widehat{H}_{t}^{E}\big]
    \end{multlined}
\\
\begin{multlined}
\widehat{Q}_{t}^{K} = \big[1 - \beta^{E}\big(1 - \delta\big) - \theta\big(\frac{1}{R^{L}} - \beta^{E}\big)\big]
\mathbb{E}_{t}\big[\widehat{\lambda}_{t+1}^{E} - \lambda_{t}^{E} + \widehat{Y}_{t+1} - K_{t}\big] + \ldots \\
    \ldots + \beta^{E}\big(1 - \delta\big)\mathbb{E}_{t}\big(\widehat{Q}_{t+1}^{K} + \widehat{\lambda}_{t+1}^{E} - \widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{E}\big) + \left(1 - \beta^{E}R^{L}\right)\frac{1}{R^{L}}\theta\mathbb{E}_{t}\left[\widehat{\mu}_{t}^{E} - \widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{E} + \widehat{\theta}_{t} + \widehat{Q}_{t+1}^{K}\right]
\end{multlined}
\\
\widehat{Q}_{t}^{K} = \left(1 + \beta^{E}\right)\Omega\widehat{I}_{t} - \beta^{E}\Omega\mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{I}_{t+1} - \Omega\widehat{I}_{t-1}
\\
\begin{multlined}
\frac{\mu^{B}}{\beta^{P}}\widehat{\mu}_{t}^{B} - \mu^{B}\gamma^{L}\big(1 - \rho_{s}\big)\mathbb{E}_{t}\mu_{t+1}^{B} = \big[p R^{L} - R^{D} + \big(1 - p\big)\tau R^{L} + \mu^{B}\gamma^{L}\big(1 - \rho_{s}\big)\big]\mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{q}_{t, t+1} + \ldots \\
    \ldots + p R^{L}\left(\widehat{p}_{t} + \widehat{R}_{t}^{L}\right) - R^{D}\widehat{R}_{t}^{D} + \left(1 - p\right)\tau R^{L}\widehat{R}_{t}^{L} - p \tau R^{L}\widehat{p}_{t}
\end{multlined}
\\
\begin{multlined}
\frac{\eta\xi\mu^{B}x}{\theta}(\widehat{\mu}_{t}^{B} + \widehat{x}_{t} - \widehat{\theta}_{t}) =   
    -\varpi\beta^{P}\big(R^{L}\big)^{2}L \theta\big(2\widehat{R}_{t}^{L} + \widehat{L}_{t} + \widehat{\theta}_{t} + \mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{q}_{t, t+1}\big) - \ldots \\
        \ldots - \eta \varpi \beta^{P}R^{L}L\left(\widehat{R}_{t}^{L} + \widehat{L}_{L} + \mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{q}_{t, t+1}\right) + 
        \varpi \tau \beta^{P}\alpha\theta^{2}R^{L}\left(\widehat{a}_{t} + 2\widehat{\theta}_{t} + \widehat{R}_{t}^{L} + \mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{q}_{t, t+1}\right) + \ldots\\
            \ldots + \eta \varpi \tau \beta^{P} \theta \left(\widehat{a}_{t} + \widehat{\theta}_{t} + \mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{q}_{t, t+1}\right)
\end{multlined}
\\
\xi\mu^{B}x\theta\left(\widehat{\mu}_{t}^{B} + \widehat{x}_{t} + \widehat{\theta}_{t}\right) = \theta\beta^{P}R^{L}pL\left(\widehat{\theta}_{t} + \widehat{R}_{t}^{L} + \widehat{p}_{t} + \widehat{L}_{t} + \mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{q}_{t, t+1}\right) + \eta \beta^{P}pL\left(\widehat{p}_{t} + \widehat{L}_{t} + \mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{q}_{t, t+1}\right)
\\
\widehat{s}_{t} = \rho_{s}\widehat{s}_{t, t-1} + \left(1 - \rho_{s}\right)\widehat{l}_{t}
\\
\widehat{x}_{t} = \frac{\widehat{l}_{t}}{1 - \gamma^{L}} - \frac{\gamma^{L}\widehat{s}_{t-1}}{1 - \gamma^{L}}
\\
\widehat{L}_{t} = \widehat{l}_{t}
\\
\widehat{Y}_{t} = \frac{C^{P}}{C}\widehat{C}_{t}^{P} + \frac{C^{E}}{Y}\widehat{C}_{t}^{E} + \frac{I}{Y}\widehat{I}_{t}
\\
H^{P}\widehat{H}_{t}^{P} + H^{E}\widehat{H}_{t}^{E} = 0
\\
\widehat{L}_{t} = \widehat{D}_{t}
\\
\begin{multlined}
C^{E}\widehat{C}_{t}^{E} + R^{L}l\left(\widehat{R}_{t-1}^{L} + \widehat{l}_{t-1}\right) =\\
    Y\widehat{Y}_{t} - WN\left(\widehat{W}_{t} + \widehat{N}_{t}\right) - I\widehat{I}_{t} - Q^{H}H^{E}\left(\widehat{H}_{t}^{E} - \widehat{H}_{t-1}^{E}\right) + \ldots\\
        \ldots + x\widehat{x}_{t} + \gamma^{L}s\widehat{s}_{t-1} + R^{L}L\left(\widehat{R}_{t-1}^{L} + \widehat{L}_{t-1}\right) -\tau a \widehat{a}_{t-1} - p R^{L}L\left(\widehat{p}_{t-1} + \widehat{R}_{t-1}^{L} + \widehat{L}_{t-1}\right) + \ldots \\
            \ldots + \tau p a \left(\widehat{p}_{t-1} + \widehat{a}_{t-1}\right)
\end{multlined}
\\
\widehat{l}_{t} = \widehat{\theta}_{t} + \widehat{a}_{t} - \widehat{R}_{t}^{L}
\\
\widehat{a}_{t} = \frac{Q^{H}H^{E}}{Q^{H}H^{E} + Q^{K}K}\mathbb{E}_{t}\left(\widehat{Q}_{t+1}^{H} + \widehat{H}_{t}^{E}\right) + \frac{Q^{K}K}{Q^{H}H^{E} + Q^{K}K}\mathbb{E}_{t}\left(\widehat{Q}_{t+1}^{K} + \widehat{K}_{t}\right)
\\
\widehat{Y}_{t} = \widehat{A}_{t} + \left(1 - \alpha\right)\widehat{N}_{t} + \alpha \phi \widehat{H}_{t-1}^{E} + \alpha \left(1 - \phi\right) \widehat{K}_{t-1}
\\
\widehat{K}_{t} = \left(1 - \delta\right) \widehat{K}_{t-1} + \delta \widehat{I}_{t}
\\
p\widehat{p}_{t} = \varpi \theta \widehat{\theta}_{t}
\\
\widehat{\kappa}_{t}^{E} = \widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{E} + \widehat{Q}_{t}^{K}
\\
\widehat{q}_{t, t+1} = \widehat{\lambda}_{t+1}^{P} - \widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{P}
    \end{gather}
\end{spreadlines}
\end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

however, in this list of equations it is easy to get lost. You should consider to insert before each equation or at list of group of related equations insert text, which describe their meaning. For this you can use `\intertext` instruction defined in the `amsmath` (and avalilble in the `mathtools` too):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, nccmath, mathtools}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\mathtoolsset{original-intertext,original-shortintertext}

\begin{document}
\section{System of Loglinear Equations}
\begin{spreadlines}{2ex}
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{gather}
\intertext{diference of ... :}    % here insert meaningful text
\beta^{P}\gamma^{P}\mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{C}_{t+1}^{P} - 
    \bigl(1 + (\gamma^{P}\bigr)^{2}\beta^{P}\bigr)     
    \widehat{C}_{t}^{P} + \gamma^{P}\widehat{C}_{t-1}^{P} 
     = \bigl(1 - \beta^{P}\gamma^{P}\bigr)\bigl(1 - \gamma^{P}\bigr) \widehat{\lambda}^{P} 
\intertext{probability:}          % here insert meaningful text
\mathbb{E}_{t}\widehat{\lambda}_{t+1}^{P}  = \widehat{\lambda}_{t}^{P} - \hat{R}_{t}^{D}
    \end{gather}
\end{fleqn}
\end{spreadlines}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @zarko. I need most of the equations in my paper centered but it's the appendix where I have these bunch of unruly equations that I need to typeset better. Using `fleqn` will align left all the equations in the document, right? I have to avoid that. Is there a way I can implement your suggestion only in my appendix while keeping my equations centered in other part of the paper?

Comment: @VKahn, left aligned is only this set of equations. If you not like this, just remove `\begin{fleqn}` ands `\end{fleqn}`. BTW, instead saying "thank you" you can upvote my answer. At least it provide much shorter and consistent code of your equations ...

Comment: just to clarify -- `fleqn` does align left all equations in the document, doesn't it? The changes are global, i.e. in the entire document. In your answer, `fleqn` aligns left only these equations because these are only equations in this case but in my original `article class` document, there are many more which are all centered. I just ran latex on my paper using `fleqn` in `documentclass` options and using `\begin{fleqn}` and `\end{fleqn}` for a set of questions but it aligned left all the equations in the entire document.

Comment: @VKahn, in my answer environment `fleqn` (defined in `nccmath`) left aligned are only its content(s). Outside of it equation is aligned as you defined in the `amsmath` package (default are centered).